# What is this plant with woody stems and scalloped leaves

Tags: identification

I Received this plant in a rented apartment. I have no idea what it is or how to care for it, and the owner neither. Please help.

[image: Unknownis Plantae]

Answer (score 1):

This plant is a nice specimen of Fabian aralia or Polyscias 'Fabian'. It is a great plant for indoors as it normally only gets about five feet tall and has a woody stem which is interesting.

This is under story growth from South East Asia and requires bright indirect light.  Strong light from a south window is not recommended so keep it in an east or west window or behind sheer curtains for a south window.

Water this plant thoroughly when the top inch of soil has gone dry. Do not let it sit in water.  Usually a weekly watering will do.  If your area has chlorinated or chloramine added to the water you could consider filtered water using the common portable water filters.

Fertilize twice in the spring, half strength at two week intervals.

This plant propagates readily from cuttings and also responds well to be being cut back as it will bud off medium and new growth.

I have rarely seen pest problems on these plants.  The most common problems are not enough light and too much water.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot upvote you because I'm new here, but you have really helped me :-)